# JpaRepository Methods in Spring Data are stuck, not returning response or error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data to connect to MySql Database.
Below is my entity class

```
package seller.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="seller")
public class SELLER {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer seller_id;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String Username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String Password;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String Name;
    @Column(name = "loggedin")
    private Integer LoggedIn;
    @Column(name = "upvotes")
    private Integer Upvotes;
    @Column(name = "downvotes")
    private Integer Downvotes;
    @Column(name = "itemssold")
    private Integer ItemsSold;

    public SELLER() {
    }

    public SELLER(String username, String password, String name, int loggedIn, int upvotes, int downvotes, int itemsSold) {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;
        this.Name = name;
        this.LoggedIn = loggedIn;
        this.Upvotes = upvotes;
        this.Downvotes = downvotes;
        this.ItemsSold = itemsSold;
    }

    public int getSellerId() {
        return seller_id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.Username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.Password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int getLoggedIn() {
        return LoggedIn;
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(int loggedIn) {
        this.LoggedIn = loggedIn;
    }

    public int getUpvotes() {
        return Upvotes;
    }

    public void setUpvotes(int upvotes) {
        this.Upvotes = upvotes;
    }

    public int getDownvotes() {
        return Downvotes;
    }

    public void setDownvotes(int downvotes) {
        this.Downvotes = downvotes;
    }

    public int getItemsSold() {
        return ItemsSold;
    }

    public void setItemsSold(int itemsSold) {
        this.ItemsSold = itemsSold;
    }
}
```

I am using JpaRepository for DB Operations. Below is my repository file

```
package seller.repo;

import seller.entity.SELLER;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface SellerRepository extends JpaRepository<SELLER, Integer> {
}
```

I have autowired SellerRepositoy and trying to invoke DB methods. I have tried to invoke save() and findAll() methods. Both of these are stuck indefinitely and neither return error nor response. (I have tried using CrudRepository also and faced the same issue with that too). I am using Maven and added following dependencies

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I aam using Java 15 in my application, not sure if it matters really in this case. I have added the below line in application properties because the tables are already created.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

I am unable to figure out what is happening here. Can anyone tell me what could be going on here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used the correct username and password in properties file?

Comment: Yes I am using root user itself and the password is correct

Comment: could you try executing an update/insert/delete and check via MySQL client whether the operation is happening or not. Also, ensure that there are no security restrictions (if you are using official laptop)

Comment: Is there any reason using column naming both underscore and camelcase?